# How to discover startup flags or command-line options for bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin-core-development

I'd like to query the Bitcoin daemon (bitcoind) to find out what startup flags (command-line options) were sent to it on startup (or the current state if it has changed, e.g. `-server=0/1` changing).

For example, I may want to know if `-addresstype`, `-disablewallet`, `-rescan`, or `-uacomment=<cmt>` or some other flag has been set.

Or for Namecoin, it would be very useful to know if `-namehistory` has been set.

Is there an RPC or any other method to find out?

---

Or, to ask the question a different way...

src/bitcoind.cpp's `bool AppInit(int argc, char* argv[])` method calls `ParseParameters(argc, argv);`, which is in src/util.cpp.

In src/util.cpp we have:

```
map<string, string> mapArgs;
static map<string, vector<string> > _mapMultiArgs;
const map<string, vector<string> >& mapMultiArgs = _mapMultiArgs;
```

To store flags/options/args.

I'd basically just like to get whatever is in those variables through bitcoind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux, get the process id of `bitcoind` and read  `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`.

On Windows, use `wmic path win32_process where "name = 'bitcoind.exe'" get commandline`